# ButtonHandler cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, swing

I've been following the Java how to program by Dietel and even though I copy the program word for word and try to import (Ctrl-Shift-O) it still cannot recognize ButtonHandler as a type. Here's my code :

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class ButtonTest1 extends JFrame{
private JButton plainB;
private JButton fancyB;

public ButtonTest1(){ //Constructer
    super("Testing buttons");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    plainB = new JButton("Plain Button");
    add(plainB); //Add to frame

    Icon bug1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bug1.png"));
    Icon bug2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bug1.png"));
    fancyB = new JButton ("Fancy Button", bug1); //set image
    fancyB.setRolloverIcon(bug1); //set rollover image
    add(fancyB);

    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler(); // <--- errors are here
    fancyB.addActionListener(handler);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you copy and compile the required `ButtonHandler` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you  someone implemented `ButtonHandler` class. It's not from Swing library

Use `ActionListener` instead or create custom:

```
public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ButtonHandler is not a standard swing class. You need to get the source code of this or make it up your self if you know it functionality. 
Do you know what library this comes from?